# Load Image/Video from IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I am working on a PWA project where I have created an IndexedDB and stored the images and videos in it. On the next reload of page, if image/video is available in IndexedDB, it should load it from there.

```
function fetchMedia(id) {
    var transaction = db.transaction(["media"]);
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("media");
    var request = objectStore.get(id);

    request.onerror = function(event) {
       console.log("Unable to retrieve daa from database!");
       return "";
    };

   request.onsuccess = function(event) {
       var imgFile = request.result;
       console.log(imgFile)
       var imgURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(imgFile);
       return imgURL;
   };
}
```

It always returns `undefined`.
When I console.log the imgFile, it shows that it's there in the IndexedDB:

[image]

File in IndexedDB:

[image]

I have also tried this but no success yet:

```
var imgURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(imgFile, {'type': 'application/octet-stream'}));
```

What's the correct approach to load the files from IndexedDB?

Answer (score 2):

If your screenshot is accurate, then `request.result` is not an image, it's an object `{id: '13388-7247-6247-62584', file: Blob, ...}`. You didn't just store the image file, you wrapped it in an object. So what you're getting back out is an object.

Try `imgFile = request.result.file;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return inside the callback, you should wrap it in a promise.